# Sudoku Solver Java

Tags: java, sudoku, solver

OK so I have programmed a Sudoku solver.. And when I run the debug to check if its going through everything.. it is.. But it does not seem to work. It will print it out, and it will change the "." to 0's. But thats as far as it goes. It will not change the 0's, to the numbers when it loops over it.

```
    public class SudokuSolver {

int[][] sudoku;
String data;
 public SudokuSolver()
 {
     getPuzzle();
     solvePuzzle(0,0);
 }

 private void getPuzzle()
 {
     try
     {
         Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/Ben/workspace/Sudoku      Solver/src/puzzle1.txt"));
         sudoku = new int[9][9];
         for(int y = 0; y<9;y++)
         {
             for(int x = 0; x<9; x++)
             {
                 data = in.next();
                 if(data.equals("."))
                     sudoku[x][y]=0;
                 else
                     sudoku[x][y] = Integer.parseInt(data);     
             }
         }
         in.close();
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {

     }
     for(int y = 0; y<9; y++)
     {

         for(int x = 0; x<9; x++)
         {
             System.out.print(sudoku[x][y]);
             if(x ==2 || x ==5)
                 System.out.print("  ");
             if(x==8)
             {
                 System.out.print("\n");
             }

         }
         if(y == 2|| y == 5)
         {
             System.out.println(" ");
         }
     }

 }

 private boolean isValid(int x, int y, int num)
 {
     int xSection = x/3;
     int ySection = y/3;

     for ( int row = 0; row < sudoku.length; row++ )
     {
         if(sudoku[row][y] == num)
         {
            return false;
         }
     }
     for( int col = 0; col < sudoku.length; col++)
     {
         if(sudoku[x][col] == num)
         {
             return false;
         }
     }


     for(int box = 3*xSection; box < 3*xSection + 3; box++)
     {
         for(int boxY = 3*ySection; boxY < 3*ySection + 3; boxY++)
         {
             if(sudoku[box][boxY] == num)
             {
                 return false;
             }
         }

     }
     return true;
 }

 private int xPosition(int x, int y)
 {
     if(x<8)
     {
         return x+1;
     }
     else 
     {
         return 0;
     }
 }

 private int yPosition(int x, int y)
 {
     if(x<8)
     {
         return y;
     }
     else
     {
         return y+1;
     }
 }
 private boolean solvePuzzle(int x, int y)
 {
     if( x >= 9 || y >= 9)
     {

         return true;
     }

     else
     {
         for(int  num = 1; num < 10; num++)
         {
             if(isValid(x,y,num))
             {
                 sudoku[x][y] = num;
                 if( solvePuzzle(xPosition(x,y), yPosition(x,y)) )
                 {
                     return true;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     sudoku[x][y] = 0;
                 }

             }


         }
         return false;
     }


 }




 public static void main(String args[])
{
SudokuSolver solver = new SudokuSolver();
}
}
```

Comment: So you're asking us to debug all your code?

Comment: Not at all. Im asking if you can visually see a problem. And leave me a hint as to where it is. If you cant visually see anything than i will need to just keep trying other things.

Answer (score 3):

You're printing the puzzle inside the `getPuzzle`-method, which is before `solvePuzzle` has been called. You need to print the puzzle after it has been solved.